# Cisco 5508 - One WLAN not pulling from Windows DHCP

Tags: dhcp, wifi

We have an existing Cisco 5508 doing all our WLAN/WAP functions. Windows 2008R2 DHCP server. There are currently 4 WLAN's, functioning properly.

We are running out of addresses on our corporate LAN/WLAN, since all devices (workstations, laptops, phones, tablets) pull from this pool. We want to offload the phones and tablets to a separate WLAN, and their own pool, so laptops and workstations can pull addresses without issue.

- I created a new VLAN, WLAN, SSID, and pool (the pool on the Windows Server).
- The new WLAN is assigned to an existing LAG. The other functioning WLANs are assigned to the same interface.
- I created a new AP Group on the 5508

  - I assigned the new WLAN to the Group.
  - I pulled one AP from the AP group, and assigned only it to the new WLAN.
- The WLAN is enabled on the 5508 and broadcasting.
- The VLAN is allowed on all trunk links. I can connect to the new WLAN, and receive a correct address in the new range, if I connect through the LAN(ethernet).

If I try to connect over WiFi, I can authenticate but cannot pull an IP address. The general settings for the new WLAN, are the same as those of the existing, working, WLAN's.

Not sure what else to check. I can post appropriate configs if needed.
EDIT:
[Pastebin link to config](http://pastebin.com/w9Jtq6xX)

Comment: would need more details on how your devices are configured.